# app from com.google.zxing.client.android source code does not work

Tags: android, barcode, barcode-scanner

I downloaded the full source from http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk and build it into an android  apk file without any problem with eclipse, but after I install the apk into my cell phone, it does not work, instead it shows: "The application Barcode Scanner(process com.google.zxing.client.android) has stopped unexpectedly, please try again"

Did  I miss anything? thanks in advance

Here is the logcat: (sorry too long)

```
08-29 09:45:48.797: E/Trace(652): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
08-29 09:45:49.027: W/dalvikvm(652): VFY: unable to resolve static field 56 (ISSUE_NUMBER) in Lcom/google/zxing/ResultMetadataType;
08-29 09:45:49.027: D/dalvikvm(652): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0017
08-29 09:45:49.048: W/dalvikvm(652): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/google/zxing/Result;)
08-29 09:45:49.077: W/dalvikvm(652): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/google/zxing/ResultPoint;)
08-29 09:45:49.077: W/dalvikvm(652): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/google/zxing/ResultPoint;)
08-29 09:45:49.087: I/dalvikvm(652): Could not find method com.google.zxing.ResultPoint.getX, referenced from method com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity.drawLine
08-29 09:45:49.097: W/dalvikvm(652): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 329: Lcom/google/zxing/ResultPoint;.getX ()F
08-29 09:45:49.097: D/dalvikvm(652): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0000
08-29 09:45:49.097: W/dalvikvm(652): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/google/zxing/Result;)
08-29 09:45:49.107: I/dalvikvm(652): Could not find method com.google.zxing.Result.getResultPoints, referenced from method com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity.drawResultPoints
08-29 09:45:49.117: W/dalvikvm(652): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 325: Lcom/google/zxing/Result;.getResultPoints ()[Lcom/google/zxing/ResultPoint;
08-29 09:45:49.117: D/dalvikvm(652): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0003
08-29 09:45:49.127: W/dalvikvm(652): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/google/zxing/Result;)
08-29 09:45:49.157: I/dalvikvm(652): Could not find method com.google.zxing.Result.toString, referenced from method com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity.handleDecodeExternally
08-29 09:45:49.157: W/dalvikvm(652): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 328: Lcom/google/zxing/Result;.toString ()Ljava/lang/String;
08-29 09:45:49.167: D/dalvikvm(652): VFY: replacing opcode 0x74 at 0x0057
08-29 09:45:49.167: I/dalvikvm(652): Could not find method com.google.zxing.Result.getText, referenced from method com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity.handleDecodeExternally
08-29 09:45:49.177: W/dalvikvm(652): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 326: Lcom/google/zxing/Result;.getText ()Ljava/lang/String;
08-29 09:45:49.177: D/dalvikvm(652): VFY: replacing opcode 0x74 at 0x014d
08-29 09:45:49.187: W/dalvikvm(652): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/google/zxing/Result;)
08-29 09:45:49.207: I/dalvikvm(652): Could not find method com.google.zxing.Result.getBarcodeFormat, referenced from method com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity.handleDecodeInternally
08-29 09:45:49.207: W/dalvikvm(652): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 322: Lcom/google/zxing/Result;.getBarcodeFormat ()Lcom/google/zxing/BarcodeFormat;
08-29 09:45:49.207: D/dalvikvm(652): VFY: replacing opcode 0x74 at 0x004c
08-29 09:45:49.247: W/dalvikvm(652): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/google/zxing/Result;)
08-29 09:45:49.277: W/dalvikvm(652): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/google/zxing/Result;)
08-29 09:45:49.277: W/dalvikvm(652): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/google/zxing/Result;)
08-29 09:45:49.287: W/dalvikvm(652): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/google/zxing/Result;)
08-29 09:45:49.297: W/dalvikvm(652): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/google/zxing/Result;)
08-29 09:45:49.307: W/dalvikvm(652): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/google/zxing/Result;)
08-29 09:45:49.307: W/dalvikvm(652): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/google/zxing/Result;)
08-29 09:45:49.317: W/dalvikvm(652): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/google/zxing/Result;)
08-29 09:45:49.328: I/dalvikvm(652): Could not find method com.google.zxing.Result.getText, referenced from method com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity.handleDecode
08-29 09:45:49.328: W/dalvikvm(652): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 326: Lcom/google/zxing/Result;.getText ()Ljava/lang/String;
08-29 09:45:49.328: D/dalvikvm(652): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0061
08-29 09:45:49.337: W/dalvikvm(652): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/google/zxing/Result;)
08-29 09:45:49.349: W/dalvikvm(652): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/google/zxing/Result;)
08-29 09:45:49.349: W/dalvikvm(652): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/google/zxing/Result;)
08-29 09:45:49.397: W/dalvikvm(652): Exception Ljava/lang/NoClassDefFoundError; thrown while initializing Lcom/google/zxing/client/android/CaptureActivity;
08-29 09:45:49.397: W/dalvikvm(652): Class init failed in newInstance call (Lcom/google/zxing/client/android/CaptureActivity;)
08-29 09:45:49.397: D/AndroidRuntime(652): Shutting down VM
08-29 09:45:49.407: W/dalvikvm(652): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
08-29 09:45:49.439: E/AndroidRuntime(652): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-29 09:45:49.439: E/AndroidRuntime(652): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
08-29 09:45:49.439: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
08-29 09:45:49.439: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
08-29 09:45:49.439: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
08-29 09:45:49.439: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1974)
08-29 09:45:49.439: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
08-29 09:45:49.439: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
08-29 09:45:49.439: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
08-29 09:45:49.439: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-29 09:45:49.439: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-29 09:45:49.439: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
08-29 09:45:49.439: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-29 09:45:49.439: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-29 09:45:49.439: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
08-29 09:45:49.439: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-29 09:45:49.439: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-29 09:45:49.439: E/AndroidRuntime(652): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.zxing.ResultMetadataType
08-29 09:45:49.439: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  at com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity.<clinit>(CaptureActivity.java:103)
08-29 09:45:49.439: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  ... 15 more
```

Comment: The reason it crashes should be in LogCat. Could you try and look in there and give the reason?

Answer (score 1):

It certainly does work: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android

You either modified the app, and that causes the crash, or you are installing on a device that can't run the app by manually side-loading.

You won't get any further help without providing the most important info of all: the stack trace!

Comment: yes, https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android work, even the apk I downloaded from http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk  works, but the apk I build from your source code does not work, I didn't change any code ,just follow the instructions:

Comment: here are what I did: 1. make a new android project from existing code: i.e, the source code I downloaded from code.google.com/p/zxing/browse/trunk; 2. build core.jar with apache ant and add it as an external jar to the project got from 1; 3. build apk from the project on 1. I got the same results either on emulator of on a real device as described in my question.

Comment: Then you did not build our project, since as you say it works. Our project has an Ant-based build. You made some new project with some subset of the project code. It "doesn't work" and you haven't said anything about what the error is.

Comment: I will paste the logcat in 3 hours, because currently I don't have an eclipse emulator. I mean the apk downloaded from your website:http://code.google.com/p/zxing/downloads/detail?name=BarcodeScanner4.2.apk&can=2&q= , which is of 519 KB, works, but the apk I build from your source code: svn checkout http://zxing.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/, which is of only 442K,  does not work.

Comment: Nope, still wrong. The app built from source today works fine. *You are not building our app*. You're building something that happens to include core.jar.

Comment: maybe you are right, but definitely I was building the project from your source code, please see the logcat below

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.zxing.ResultMetadataType  You didn't include core.jar. Again, *you have already said you are not building from our project*. Otherwise you'd be using Ant, not Eclipse.

Comment: I use ant to build core.jar from your source core/*, then I use eclipse to create an android project with your source android/*. If I don't include core.jar in the android project based on your source, there would be many errors which would not allow me to build apk.

Comment: Right. You aren't building our app. You're building yours. Put core.jar in libs/

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, the instruction I read before never say that,  I was only told to added core.jar as the external jar to the project. It works. You are the man, the greatest!!!